# Access a 16-bit DLL

Tags: c, java-native-interface

I have been given the task to upgrade an existing 16-bit desktop application originally written in GFA Basic.
I want to know if there is a possibility to access the functions inside these 16-bit Dlls via C/JNI (or any other programming language).
I guess, I have to write some sort of an intermediate DLL to access the functionalities from a Java class (or any other language).

**For example DLLTEST has the implementation of the functions**

```
$Library
'LNK Exe  d:\DLLtest.dll

Procedure LIBMAIN(hInst&, DSeg&, HpSz&, lpCmd%)

  q_dllname$ = "DLLtext.dll"
  RETVAL 1  ' If LIBMAIN is used, then RETVAL must be TRUE

Return
  
Procedure WEP(SysExit&) 
                 ' ##############################################

  // SysExit = 1 - ExitWindows

  // SysExit = 0 - DLL vrijgegeven

  RETVAL 0  ' ???????????

Return
  
Procedure TextTest(dc&)

  $EXPORT TextTest

  SETDC dc&

  RGBColor 0
  
  Local  t$ = "Hello world" + Chr$(0)

  Text 10, 10, t$
  Beep

  ~TextOut(dc&, 10, 50, V:t$, Len(t$))

  Beep

Return
```

**The above DLL file is in turn used by TESTTEXT.exe**

```
// destination exe file

'LNK Exe d:\testtext.exe

DLL #7, "dlltest.dll"

DECL LONG TextTest(W)

ENDDLL

OpenW # 1

h& = Win(1)

SETDC GetDC(h&)

' RGBCOLOR 0

' GRAPHMODE R2_COPYPEN

~@@TextTest(_DC())

KeyGet k%

CloseW # 1

FreeDll 7

End
```

I want to rewrite this TESTTEXT.exe using Java/C (or any other modern programming language). I guess, I need to build a bridge between this DLL and the new EXE by building another DLL.
I was hoping to get some help about writing this intermediate DLL.

Also, let me know if this kind of solution makes sense!

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your question could benefit from formatting the code as code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
Though I am disappointed by the solution..:(
I came across this link: http://www.mvps.org/vbvision/thunks.htm
If I have understood this article correctly, I guess, I could use the Win32 SDK on my XP machine and try to find a way out of this mess by writing the thunk script.

Comment: @niobie:although you can run the SDK stuff on the XP machine (assuming you can find an old enough SDK) you're still stuck with the fact that what you produce (the code using the Flat Thunk) will only run on Windows 9x/Me.

Comment: Oh! I get it now..This might sound a little stupid..
But I wonder how this 16 Bit application is still running on XP..
Some functionalities have been compromised on but still it seems to be working fine..

Comment: @niobie:Running the application on XP isn't a problem, because calling a 16-bit DLL from 16-bit executable doesn't require thunking. It just requires loading both in the same virtual machine. XP also supports "Genric Thunks", which work in the other direction (16-bit executable using 32-bit DLL). They supported flat thunking on Win9x because the OS itself supported 32-bit executables, but parts of the OS were written as 16-bit DLLs. Since XP doesn't use 16-bit DLLs, they didn't need it and don't support it.

Answer (score 3):

Using a 16-bit DLL from a 32-bit application involves what Microsoft calls (called) "flat thunking". Flat Thunking is available *only* in the 16/32-bit hybrid versions of Windows (Windows 95, 98, 98SE, Me).

What you want is not supported on any reasonably current version of Windows.

Comment: Jerry's right. The only way that you could even think about doing this in any current Windows is to write a 16-bit program which loads the 16-bit DLL in the 16-bit virtual machine and then some provide some infrastructure to essentially RPC over to that 16-bit process... obviously this is pretty much untenable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jerry.  In the meantime you might start looking at this post:
http://www.atari-forum.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=4826&start=20